# Change Mahout Item based recommeder output format into table

Tags: hadoop, hive, mahout, collaborative-filtering

I am using Mahout Item based recommendation algorithms, In the end when we are getting the result in "XXX   [y:z, y2;z2......]" format. I want to create a table on that in format:

- XXX   y  z
- XXX   y2 z2

I am using HIVE for that. So I have created a table and then using "explode()" function but problem is that "[" is also coming in the result as

- XXX [y  z
- ..
- XXX yn zn]

How can i remove bracket from the result.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `regexp_replace` function ([documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions)) to filter out square brackets, and then use `explode` as you did already.